# Cases with Emails Created by user

Tags: email, reporting, servicecloud

I am creating a report in Salesforce using the Cases with Emails standard report.  I am trying to get a count of how many emails are sent  by each CSA.  Because the standard report only allows you to see the Case owner, we cannot pull a report showing how many emails each CSA has sent.  It only allows me to tie in the the Case owner for any outbound Emails that are sent out.  However when I go into the outbound email message details in Salesforce As you can see from the attached screen shot, it does store who sent the email which is independent of the case owner.  My question is, how do I pull a report and include the field created by for that specific email?

**The goal of this report is to get a total count of outbound emails by CSA, where the CSA is not always the Case Owner***

[image]

Comment: Hi Nancy, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Your post does not currently contain a question, which makes it kind of hard to figure out what you're asking!

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I added more information hopefully that is a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

That report type doesn't seem to have access to the createdBy field on the emailMessage object. Since that is a standard report type you cannot edit it to add the field so your only choice is to create a custom cases with emails report type.

Alternatively, since as you said, the owner of the case changes over time and this cannot be replied upon, run a report directly on the EmailMessage object. This again would be a custom report type but you wont bog it down with un-needed information. Any information you do need can be gleamed from the parent field on the EmailMessage object.

If you can't create a report to pull in data from the parent object. You can create custom formula fields on the EmailMessage object that can pull in the data from the parent case.

Just a few ideas but to summarize the answer to your question: You can't without a custom report type.